# A constant is out of scope but clearly defined (or so I believe)

Tags: haskell

I am trying out Scalpel to scrape a website but got into an out of scope error using their own example code. That example is found on their [github page](https://github.com/fimad/scalpel), section *My Scraping Target Doesn't Return The Markup I Expected*.

I am using the `ghc-8.6.4` Haskell compiler.

My `packages.yaml` dependencies are:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- http-conduit
- http-client
- http-client-tls
- http-types
- scalpel
```

The code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Example where

import Text.HTML.Scalpel
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client as HTTP
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client.TLS as HTTP
import qualified Network.HTTP.Types.Header as HTTP

-- Create a new manager settings based on the default TLS manager that updates
-- the request headers to include a custom user agent.
managerSettings :: HTTP.ManagerSettings
managerSettings = HTTP.tlsManagerSettings {
  HTTP.managerModifyRequest = \req -> do
    req' <- HTTP.managerModifyRequest HTTP.tlsManagerSettings req
    return $ req' {
      HTTP.requestHeaders = (HTTP.hUserAgent, "My Custom UA")
                          : HTTP.requestHeaders req'
    }
}

main = do
    manager <- Just <$> HTTP.newManager managerSettings
    html <- scrapeURLWithConfig (def { manager }) url $ htmls anySelector
    maybe printError printHtml html
  where
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    printError = putStrLn "Failed"
    printHtml = mapM_ putStrLn
```

As you can see from the code sample, the `manager` constant is sitting next to the `def` function. But it seems like it is hiding `manager` somehow... I can't put my finger on what's wrong.

The entire console output from the `stack build` command, which contains the reported error:

```
jroyer$ stack build
my-okr-haskeller-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library for my-okr-haskeller-0.1.0.0..
Building library for my-okr-haskeller-0.1.0.0..
[2 of 3] Compiling Example          ( src/Example.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Example.o )

/Users/jroyer/Projects/bizgithub/my-okr-haskeller/src/Example.hs:26:40: error: Not in scope: ‘manager’
   |
26 |     html <- scrapeURLWithConfig (def { manager }) url $ htmls anySelector
   |                                        ^^^^^^^


--  While building package my-okr-haskeller-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/jroyer/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build lib:my-okr-haskeller exe:my-okr-haskeller-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: That's not the error I get. I get that `def` is not in scope (and after fixing that, a type error -- though perhaps I got a different version of the library than you did).

Comment: I have scalpel-core 0.5.1, which seems to have the `def` method defined in this code source: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel-0.5.1/src/src/Text/HTML/Scalpel/Internal/Scrape/URL.hs

Comment: That version uses `def` from `Data.Default`, but it doesn't re-export it. If you want to use that `def` too, you'll have to do `import Data.Default (def)`.

Comment: For me, importing the `Data.Default (def)` function explicitly still gets me the same error: `error: Not in scope: ‘manager’`

Comment: Are you sure you have copied and pasted the exact code you're trying to compile? Can you please paste the *entire* error?

Comment: @DanielWagner ok let me paste the entire console output of the build. And yes I have copied and pasted the exact code, I just tried again to make sure this is legitimate.

Comment: Hm. Your error says line 26, but line 26 of the code you've pasted has just `where` on it. Are you *sure* you've pasted the exact code you're trying to compile?

Comment: Does the Haskell community has some sort of equivalent to jsfiddle where I can load the required libraries, write the code and have it executed to reproduce my issue, in order to easily share what is happening?

Comment: There is a module definition that I added from the example code which adds two lines (i.e. module Example where), for it to compile properly when executing stack build. I will update it with the module definition if you want. The rest is the same.

Comment: Wow, this is a really long discussion for what seems obvious.  1. Record syntax needs a `{ field = value}` not just `{ value }`.  2. Yeah, from my view there's a missing import but from a common enough module and I did see your presented error first - perhaps that's a difference of compiler version from what @DanielWagner is using.

I guess tired me is trying to say thanks for posting copious information and conversing on your question, I know us SO denizens have grown weary of incomplete/abandoned/inaccurate questions which leads to all this up-front vetting just to help someone.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `{ manager }` is correct with [`NamedFieldPuns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=namedfieldpuns#extension-NamedFieldPuns) on, which it is.

Comment: Ah, thanks Daniel. Unclear why that error always with that extension but I did reproduce.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I don't think you did. Look at the error in the question carefully: as called out in the comments, the question's claimed error does *not* say that `def` is out of scope, but that `manager` is. So in your answer, you fixed a different error than the question-asker says they need help fixing, and changed a thing that wasn't broken in the first place!

Comment: Hurm, seems likely.  Tired me has done stupider things.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It does seem like a curious question. My current top hypothesis is that OP is lying somehow. Not out of malice or anything like that, just by being mistaken. e.g. I could imagine the pattern "copy and paste from documentation to file, hit a wrong keystroke by accident without noticing that deletes a letter from the `manager` binding on line 25; save; then, when writing the SO question, copy and paste from documentation again instead of from the actual file". You'll notice that in the edit from 9 hours ago, a new `Just` appeared (!) which supports the hypothesis.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson ...hence my repeated prodding to make *double plus sure* that the code in the file is exactly as represented here. If you can think of other small mistakes (perhaps they're compiling a different file than they think they are...? or their editor's view of the file is out of synch with what's actually on disk...???) that would lead to this kind of lie I'm sure both the asker and I are all ears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:  I can reproduce the asker's problem with an old version of scalpel, which the asker mentioned they were using:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Example          ( Main.hs, /var/folders/m7/_2kqsz4n4c3ck8050glq4ggr0000gn/T/cabal-repl.-26184/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.6.4/fake-package-0/x/script/build/script/script-tmp/Example.o )

Main.hs:34:40: error: Not in scope: ‘manager’
   |
34 |     html <- scrapeURLWithConfig (def { manager }) url $ htmls anySelector
   |                                        ^^^^^^^
./so.hs  16.94s user 3.89s system 114% cpu 18.155 total
```

This is a suboptimal error message that seems to result from using named field puns and a variable that is not a field name.  That is, `Config` in that version of `scalpel` does not have a manager field.  We can reproduce this issue in a smaller example:

```
% cat test.hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
data Foo = Foo { bar :: Int } deriving (Show)
main :: IO ()
main = print (Foo { zar})
 where zar = 23 :: Int
% ghc test.hs
...snipt...
test.hs:4:21: error:
    Not in scope: ‘zar’
    Perhaps you meant ‘bar’ (line 3)
  |
4 | main = print (Foo { zar})
```

The solution is thus to update to a newer version of scalpel.

<strike>html <- scrapeURLWithConfig (def { manager }) url $ htmls anySelector</strike>

I have no idea what this is supposed to be. Specifically `(def { manager })`. That isn't any syntax I'm familiar with.

Where you have `manager`, there should be a field.  For example:

```
def { someField = someValue }
```

not what you have of `def { someValue }` which makes no sense.

Ah, NamedFieldPuns.  I've honestly never used them and looking at them I find myself perfering RecordWildCards.  Moving on.

Looking at the haddocks, the field name is `manager` so you have a `manager` field and a `manager` value for the named field pun. I needed to add an import for `def`.  At the same time I took the liberty of using `cabal` and a shebang to be explicit about all the packages:

```
#! /usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends:
      base >= 4
    , scalpel == 0.6.0
    , http-types == 0.12.3
    , http-client-tls == 0.3.5.3
    , http-client == 0.6.4
    , data-default == 0.7.1.1
-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Default
import Text.HTML.Scalpel
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client as HTTP
import qualified Network.HTTP.Client.TLS as HTTP
import qualified Network.HTTP.Types.Header as HTTP

-- Create a new manager settings based on the default TLS manager that updates
-- the request headers to include a custom user agent.
managerSettings :: HTTP.ManagerSettings
managerSettings = HTTP.tlsManagerSettings {
  HTTP.managerModifyRequest = \req -> do
    req' <- HTTP.managerModifyRequest HTTP.tlsManagerSettings req
    return $ req' {
      HTTP.requestHeaders = (HTTP.hUserAgent, "My Custom UA")
                          : HTTP.requestHeaders req'
    }
}

main = do
    manager <- Just <$> HTTP.newManager managerSettings
    html <- scrapeURLWithConfig (def { manager = manager }) url $ htmls anySelector
    maybe printError printHtml html
  where
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    printError = putStrLn "Failed"
    printHtml = mapM_ putStrLn
```

Which seems to run well.  Notice the module containing `main` should itself be `Main`.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with the extension, it seems that [NamedFieldPuns](https://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/glasgow_exts.html#record-puns), which is enabled here, should enable precisely this syntax?

Comment: Indeed, thanks.  I'll need to look harder to see why the error appeared.

Comment: I see your point.  Clearly the asker needed help and comments were not sufficient communication.  META: There are two categories of answers I see on SO.  1. Answers to questions, which usually generalize to help others 2. Examples and dialog that gets an individual unstuck.  I don't think this question will resolve with an answer of the first type.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Indeed, solving these situations are sometimes tricky.. Although I didn't find the exact reason why `manager` was out of scope, I explicitly overridden the scalpel version to 0.6.0 in my `stack.yaml` configuration to align with your answer (I was on 0.5.1 as previously mentioned) and then, I started to see the error with the `def` function not being imported, which I imported (again). That did the trick, it's all working now. Solving this compilation error is all that matters to me right now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I am marking this as the solution, where the answer is to upgrade the scalpel library version from 0.5.1 to 0.6.0. @ThomasM.DuBuisson if you want to mention this explicitly int he answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasM.DuBuisson for digging further! It's now much clearer why I had this error and a good teaching for me on my way to learning Haskell. =)